# Featured tags: do I get displayed only questions out of this range of interest?

Tags: support, questions, interesting-page

I am impressed by Stack Overflow and its possibilities.

I am interested in all things like Programming Python, perl, etc, so I added the following tags to the featured ones:

perl php mysql python-requests mechanize www-mechanize mechanize-python scrapy web-scraping python beautifulsoup

How do I get displayed only questions with these tags?